# How do i get the field to pass to another sql phrase in a join statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to do this and i want the 'a' in the 2nd sql statement to be the 'a' in the first query.

```
Select 
    a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a2,b2 
from
    (Select 
        a as a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h 
    from 
        `table1` 
    inner join 
        `table2` 
    where 
        table1.a=table2.a and b=0)z 
join
    (Select 
        a2,b2
    from
        `table3`
    where
        b2=1 and a=a2
    group by b2)x
group by a
```

This results that 'a' is unknown.

I tried to do these to 'a' in the 2nd sql statement:

z.a, a1, z.a1

Please guide me.

Comment: Try inner join by the a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do inner join on the common column

```
Select 
    a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a2,b2 
from
    (Select 
        a as a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h 
    from 
        `table1` 
    inner join 
        `table2` 
    where 
        table1.a=table2.a and b=0)z 
Inner join
    (Select 
        a2,b2
    from
        `table3`
    where
        b2=1 
    group by b2)x
On z.a=x.a2
group by a1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is also what PeterRing said. This solve my problem. +1


Got another follow up question, if i use inner join, if no record in the other sql statement but in the other sql statement has, it wont give any records, will it?

Comment: Yes..inner joim returns only matching rows

Comment: I didn't try beforehand doing the left join statement and just asked directly. Sorry for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing column names

```
Select 
    a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a2,b2 
from
    (Select 
        table1.a as a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h 
    from 
        `table1` 
    inner join 
        `table2` 
    where 
        table1.a=table2.a and b=0)z 
join
    (Select 
        a2,b2
    from
        `table3`
    where
        b2=1 and z.a=a2
    group by b2)x
group by a1
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for the fast reply though.